# Duplicating form on button click

Tags: php, symfony, duplicates, formbuilder

I have a very simple form with 2 fields, all I want to do is a button where the user could duplicate this form to add multiple entries in one batch.

[What i would like to do (I can't integrate images yet, sry..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Bzu.png)

I'm not sure on how to integrate this, I found [some documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) about forms collections but i'm not sure if it fits to my needs, plus it was for Symfony 2, i'm using the latest version (Symfony 5)

I thought I could add my button with `href='#?duplicateForm=1'` and handle that with the controller & the type but that does not seem to be a proper solution to me... Bad idea to throw a user input in a `for` statement.

My Type class:

The form is different depending on the current user role, the admins have more fields.

```php
class NetworkFolderAccessType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['type'] == 'ADMIN_FORM'){
            $builder
            ->add('userId', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => function ($user) {
                    return $user->getNom() . ' ' . $user->getPrenom() .' ('. $user->getUsername().')';
                },
                'label'=>'Demandeur',
                'attr'=> [
                    'class'=>'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('validated',ChoiceType::class,[
                'expanded'=>false,
                'multiple'=>false,
                'choices'=>['Oui'=>true,'Non'=>false],
                'label'=>'Validé par le responsable',
                'attr'=> [
                    'class'=>'form-control'
                ],
                'choice_attr'=> [
                    'class'=>'checkbox-inline'
                ]
            ]);
        }
        if($options['type'] == 'USER_FORM' || $options['type'] == 'ADMIN_FORM'){
            $builder
            ->add('dataPath',TextType::class,[
                'attr'=> [
                    'class'=>'form-control'
                ],
                'label'=>'Chemin d\'accès'
            ])
            ->add('rights', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Lecture' => 'read',
                    'Écriture' => 'write',
                    'Lecture & Écriture' => 'readwrite',
                ],
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label'=>'Droits d\'accès',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
            ])
        ;
        } 
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => NetworkFolderAccess::class,
            'type'=>'USER_FORM'
        ]);
    }
}
```

My controller :

```php
/**
     * @Route("/new", name="network_folder_access_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $networkFolderAccess = new NetworkFolderAccess();

        if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        $form = $this->createForm(NetworkFolderAccessType::class, $networkFolderAccess, ['type'=>'ADMIN_FORM']);
        elseif ($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
        $form = $this->createForm(NetworkFolderAccessType::class, $networkFolderAccess, ['type'=>'USER_FORM']);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $networkFolderAccess->setDateDemand(new DateTime());
            if ($this->IsGranted('ROLE_USER') && !$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
            $networkFolderAccess->setUserId($this->security->getUser());

            $entityManager->persist($networkFolderAccess);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('network_folder_access_index');
        }

        return $this->render('network_folder_access/new.html.twig', [
            'network_folder_access' => $networkFolderAccess,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html. If you followed this tutorial and you discover that you do not have a "parent entity" and thus there is no relation than you can still work with the main form and child form types

Comment: sorry i think i may have misunderstood your comment, but i do have a OneToMany relation : One User can have many NetworkFolderAccesses.
Thanks though for the link to the current documentation for forms collections, i thought it only existed for the 2.0 version since there's no link to the newest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you had a look on these [tutorials on symfonyCast](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/refactoring-for-new-collections) ? It would fit your needs perfectly (from chapter 18 to the end)

It will show you how to use the OneToMany relation, the form prototyping and the Collection type to add and/or delete embeded forms.